# Angular repeater properties change?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I am creating tiles based on personal benefits. I want to use ng-repeat to iterate through the different benefits a logged in user may have then render the tile that is populated with property info. That said, what is the best approach to this or an example you can share if for instance each benefit returned in the array differs just a little? What I mean is this, the JSON data returned by the API call is something like:

```
  "Benefits": [
    {
      "beginDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2014-12-31T00:00:00",
      "balance": 855,
      "annualAmt": 1000,
      "contribAmt": 958.41,
      "claimAmt": 145,
      "reimbAmt": 0,
      "amtToClaim": 145,
      "lastIncurDate": "2014-11-20T00:00:00",
      "lastSubmitDate": "2015-03-31T00:00:00",
      "id": "hECT9z9f0kzx9dFKR1aHaQ%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FSA",
      "name": "Day Care FSA",
      "planTypeId": 1,
      "benefitTypeId": 2,
      "benefitCode": "DCFSA"
    },
    {
      "beginDate": "2014-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2014-12-31T00:00:00",
      "balance": 624.05,
      "annualAmt": 720,
      "contribAmt": 750,
      "claimAmt": 95.95,
      "reimbAmt": 25,
      "amtToClaim": 70.95,
      "lastIncurDate": "2014-12-31T00:00:00",
      "lastSubmitDate": "2015-03-31T00:00:00",
      "id": "nBigB7RCvDmxg9xGph8SGA%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FSA",
      "name": "Health Care FSA",
      "planTypeId": 1,
      "benefitTypeId": 1,
      "benefitCode": "HCFSA"
    },
    {
      "beginDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "balance": 3000,
      "annualAmt": 3000,
      "contribAmt": 0,
      "claimAmt": 0,
      "reimbAmt": 0,
      "amtToClaim": 0,
      "lastIncurDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "lastSubmitDate": "2016-03-31T00:00:00",
      "id": "WUNKhLDimFQc1Fa7JV0nBA%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FSA",
      "name": "Day Care FSA",
      "planTypeId": 1,
      "benefitTypeId": 2,
      "benefitCode": "DCFSA"
    },
    {
      "beginDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "balance": 2500,
      "annualAmt": 2500,
      "contribAmt": 0,
      "claimAmt": 0,
      "reimbAmt": 0,
      "amtToClaim": 0,
      "lastIncurDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "lastSubmitDate": "2016-03-31T00:00:00",
      "id": "eYjicL2j0ogvtN%2bjEs8kGw%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FSA",
      "name": "Health Care FSA",
      "planTypeId": 1,
      "benefitTypeId": 1,
      "benefitCode": "HCFSA"
    },
    {
      "beginDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "balance": 4000,
      "annualAmt": 4000,
      "claimAmt": 0,
      "payableAmt": 0,
      "reimbAmt": 0,
      "amtToClaim": 0,
      "id": "NkO5zMJvWr%2f1XfSG3x%2fXRA%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "HRAPrime",
      "name": "HRADED",
      "planTypeId": 4,
      "benefitTypeId": 14,
      "benefitCode": "HRADED"
    },
    {
      "balance": 0,
      "ordersPlaced": 0,
      "fundsUsed": 0,
      "lastOrder": 0,
      "currentOrder": 0,
      "currentOrderMonth": "September",
      "lastUpdateDay": "2015-08-25T00:00:00",
      "id": "MvI9bsKE08CQa8AdaymmPw%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FlexiPass",
      "name": "Flexi-Pass Transit/Vanpool Benefit",
      "planTypeId": 6,
      "benefitTypeId": 29,
      "benefitCode": "FCTRANS"
    },
    {
      "balance": 0,
      "ordersPlaced": 0,
      "fundsUsed": 0,
      "lastOrder": 100,
      "currentOrder": 0,
      "currentOrderMonth": "September",
      "lastUpdateDay": "2015-08-25T00:00:00",
      "id": "YfZ10n9I%2bgbmxBjoqwVYPw%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FlexiPass",
      "name": "Flexi-Pass Parking Benefit",
      "planTypeId": 6,
      "benefitTypeId": 30,
      "benefitCode": "FCPARK"
    },
    {
      "balance": 0,
      "ordersPlaced": 0,
      "fundsUsed": 0,
      "lastOrder": 0,
      "currentOrder": 0,
      "currentOrderMonth": "September",
      "lastUpdateDay": "2015-08-25T00:00:00",
      "id": "j0AQs5lJksAZb%2fVYcwwSSg%3d%3d",
      "benefit": "FlexiPass",
      "name": "Flexi-Pass Bicycle Benefit",
      "planTypeId": 6,
      "benefitTypeId": 31,
      "benefitCode": "FCBICY"
    }
  ],
```

and my html for this running through a repeater is:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>My Benefits</h1>
    <div class="col-md-4 beneTile" data-ng-repeat="Benefits in ppt">
        <h4> {{ ppt.name }} </h4>
        <div style="margin: 5px;">    
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Balance:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.balance }} </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Annual Election:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.annualAmt }} </li>
            </ul>       
             <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Contributed to Date:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.contribAmt }} </li>
            </ul>  
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Claimed to Date:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.claimAmt }} </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Reimbursed to Date:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.reimbAmt }} </li>
            </ul>       
             <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Amount left to Claim:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.amtToClaim }} </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Last Day to Incur:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.Benefits[0].lastIncurDate }} </li>
            </ul>       
             <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Last Day to Submit:</li>
                <li> {{ ppt.lastSubmitDate }} </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

So you can see where the issue is right? Basically, the tiles themselves should look the same and in those cases where one benefit may have an additional property or something like that, Angular would be smart enough to add that in (kind of like a filter or something). The screenshot represents this with blank fields, but the concepts is the same. Seems there should be something easier than running through a switch or case statement. Ideas please?

[image]

Thanks much!

Comment: "So you can see where the issue is right?"  No, not really.  If you are trying to suggest that you have two elements which are slightly different, it's better to just list the two elements and highlight the differences, instead of trying to list your entire code and hope someone else can spot the differences on a casual read through without your specific domain knowledge.

Comment: also, I suspect that you meant to write `ppt in Benefits` rather than `Benefits in ppt`.

Comment: Yes, meant Benefits in ppt . What I mean is, each tile should render the same, as rhe picture is just a diagram of what it would look like if all the tiles were the same. As said, some tiles may not show "Amount left to Claim:" or something like that. As you can see from the properties, they do vary.

Comment: my point is, anyone studying the data would have to look very hard to find the differences, and many will not take that much time.  Aside from that, you haven't really asked a question, only mentioned that you are having issues with fields that change, and mentioned switch or case statements which you don't show.  At least in your comments, you allude to a potential difference, but you still aren't really clear what you want rendered in this circumstance.  The code you *did* provide looks to work correctly, and it's not obvious why it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have no idea of what you are asking (!), but I'll try anyway: 
I would make a list of properties you want to show:

```
$scope.props = [
    { name: "balance", label: "Balance"}
    { name: "annualAmt", label: "Annual Election"}
    ....
];
```

(You could fetch them from your stucture, but you have to define your labels somewhere...)
Then display it using nested repeats something like:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="ppt in Benefits">
    <h4> {{ ppt.name }} </h4>
    <div data-ng-repeat="prop in Props">
        <ul class="list-inline" ng-show="ppt[prop.name].length > 0">
            <li> {{ prop.label }} </li>
            <li> {{ ppt[prop.name] }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6BjheSkR8dTjziZB86AT?p=preview

Is that what you mean with "add that in (kind of like a filter or something)."?
Or... If you are talking about `ppt.Benefits[0]`? Does this mean you have a $scope.ppt somewhere (that you for some mysterious reason choose not to show)?

Then what about transforming your response when you receive the data? (Which you are not showing either...!) You should be able to make Benefits.lastIncurDate look like whatever you find usable.